# Debugging slider in React (styled components)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I'm at the initial state of trying to make a slider where the cards(divs) move left and right on click. The onClick handler is working. However, my issue is that when I run the project the cards start 230px away from the left arrow. I want it initially next to the left arrow and have the 230px spacing happen (using `transform: translateX`) when the left arrow is clicked.

Project at https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-cache-pk4j8

Parent Component (containers/card.js)

```
import React,{useRef,useState} from 'react';
import { Card } from '../components';
import { CardItemContainer } from './card-item';

export function CardContainer() 
 {

   const [scroll,setScroll]=useState('left')

    return(
        <Card>
            <Card.ArrowSliderLeft setScroll={setScroll}  />
                <Card.List scroll={scroll}>
                  <CardItemContainer/>
                  <CardItemContainer/>
                </Card.List>
            <Card.ArrowSliderRight setScroll={setScroll} />
        </Card>
    )}
```

Child Components(componets/card/index.js)

```
import {ArrowBackIosOutlined,ArrowForwardIosOutlined} from "@material-ui/icons";
import React from 'react';

import {Container,Wrapper,List,ArrowSliderLeft} from './styles/card';
 

export default function Card({ children, ...restProps }) {
   
       return <Container {...restProps}>{children}</Container>   
}


Card.List=function CardList({scroll,children,...restProps})
{
   return <List{...restProps} active={scroll}>
             {children}
         </List>
}

Card.ArrowSliderLeft = function HeaderArrowBackIosOutlinedSymbol({  setScroll,...restProps })
 {
    
const handleClick =e=>{
        setScroll(e)
     }

    return <ArrowSliderLeft  {...restProps } >
              <ArrowBackIosOutlined id="sliderLeft" onClick={()=>handleClick('left')}/>
           </ArrowSliderLeft>
}

Card.ArrowSliderRight = function HeaderArrowForwardIosOutlinedSymbol({setScroll,...restProps}) {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    setScroll(e);
  };
  
  return (
    <ArrowSliderRight {...restProps}>
      <ArrowForwardIosOutlined 
        id="sliderRight" 
        onClick={() => handleClick("right")}
                               />
    </ArrowSliderRight>
  );
};
```

styled components (components/card/styles/card.js)

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Container=styled.div`
width:100%;
margin-top:10px;
`

export const List=styled.div`

margin-left:50px;
display:flex;
width:max-content;
margin-top:10px;
transform:${({ active }) => (active==='left'  ? 'translateX(230px)' : 'translateX(0px)')}

`
export const ArrowSliderLeft=styled.div`
  
`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm misunderstanding the question, but if you just remove "left" as the default value from `const [scroll,setScroll]=useState('left')` that should do it, right?

I forked your example; https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-rubin-8d00s?file=/src/containers/card.js